# How to open password protected pdf using pdfjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf.js

I have react application which is opening up pdf documents, when i try to open password protected pdf, it gives me JS Exception.

One way I can solve this issue is get PDF in try catch, If I get exception then I ask user for password and then I open pdf with that password. **I know how to open password protected pdf**.

Is above mentioned technique is a proper way or there is any other way to do it?

Comment: Post your try-catch solution and we could think about "any other way to do it". No code, no answer...